# <select> for many entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model

I have a model of the `Aircraft` and `FleetItem` model:

Aircraft.cs:

```
public class Aircraft : IDbEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int? MaxAltitude { get; set; }

    public int? MaxSpeed { get; set; }

    public int? NOfFirstClassSeats { get; set; }

    public int? NOfBusinessClassSeats { get; set; }

    public int? NOfEconomyClassSeats { get; set; }
}
```

FleetItem.cs:

```
public class FleetItem : IDbEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string RegNumber { get; set; }

    public int AirplaneId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AirplaneId")]
    public virtual Aircraft Airplane { get; set; }
}
```

So, actually - `FleetItem` contains foreign key to `Aircraft` and registration number of the plane (`regnumber` is unique).

View Index.cshtml that I have now:

```
@model Core.Models.FleetItem
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = $"Add new plane to fleet";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<form method="post" asp-controller="Fleet" asp-action="Add" asp-antiforgery="true">
    <!-- todo add plane select -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegNumber" class="control-label">Registration number:</label>
        <input asp-for="RegNumber" class="form-control" type="text" />
        <span asp-validation-for="RegNumber"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I need to link `FleetItem` with `Aircraft`.

Solution that I found: select all airplanes and pass them into view and output it using `<select>`.

This solution is suitable when I have a few Aircraft. But, if I have 1000+ aircrafts? It will be too big for the `<select>` list. So, I think about any search that returns Aircraft. It will be awesome. But, how to implement this? I think that solution somewhere exists but I can't find it.

Or can you suggest the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of user experience the best option is to add a search box that will keep filtering your Aircraft on the flight, i.e. it will issue a request to a server to show say top 10 elements. This is a common approach to implement such a functionality.

I am not sure if you can easily implement in directly in the MVC model, but if you have some client-side framework, you can use it to achieve this. E.g. you can use popular [select2](https://select2.github.io/) control that is capable of doing such things. As it's name suggests it's kind of an improvement over ordinary select to add all that stuff that you need.

Of course you could always implement it yourself for a simple case with ordinary input and a div popup.

P.S. You can google a little how to connect select2 with MVC e.g. [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/wiki/.Net-MVC-Example). But generally it should not be a big deal since it's just some AJAX request in web api that you need to support with the data + some client side script to connect it to your model.

Comment: Yep, it is what i need, thank you. But can you help me with Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/inputData ? Google says that i need to use full version of the select2, but select2 4.0.3 from bower doesn't contains full version.

Comment: Answer: use `<select>` except `<input>`. Thank you again :)

Comment: You are welcome, I did not have too much experience with select2 myself, so could not help you out there :)